# Open .doc file without providing the path of its handler application C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, operating-system

I need to open PDF and DOC files within my C++ project, the only limitation I have I can not use ShellExecute and WinExeute for opening extension files.

Now, I tried to open the files with WMI queries and OpenProcess() , but both these procedures require the Handler application path along with the path of DOC/PDF file.

I can not give the default handler application path, Is there any way to open files directly without specifying the Handler Application Path ?

Comment: I have to print a document but I can't plug a printer on my computer. Is there any reason you can't use ShellExecute? Is it OK to find the path of _handling application_? Can you execute them through cmd.exe?

Comment: Yes, It is OK to find the path of handling application !
Pls suggest the correct way of finding the default handling application path, one way could be finding it through Registry ?

Comment: The correct way is ShellExecute. Your Windows version knows where the relevant settings are. Note: It's not sufficient to know the app path. Well, for .doc it probably is. You need the full command line, which might have `/open=%1` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve which application is associated with file you need to open. A start point [here](https://superuser.com/questions/266268/where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-fil) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It may be tricky because of various details you may need to take into account but it's what `ShellExecute` does.

If you know which application you want to use then search it in *known applications* (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`). This is useful only if you know which file type you're handling and which application you want to use.

A more easy method may be to execute `cmd.exe`, you won't call `ShellExecute` and it'll do the job for you (executing default verb):

```
cmd /c MyFile.txt
```

In code (just an example...):

```
CreateProcess("cmd.exe",
        "/c c:\\MyFile.txt",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &startupInfo,
        &processInformation);
```

Comment: I am just trying to create a POC for the same operation done by ShellExecute(), wherein I wish to replicate its functionality.

In case, I get the default application path successfully using registry or any Win32 API for getting default handler application paths, It could be done by other ways also.

Comment: @WindowsProgrammer OK, I understand. I added more links anyway to summarize you can resolve file association (with Registry) or executing cmd.exe with CreateProcess (it'll call ShellExecute for you).

Comment: The proper way is to call `CMD.EXE /c START c:\MyFile.txt`. But it still violates the limitation of the question. This still calls ShellExecute, just in an indirect way. @WindowsProgrammer, what is the real problem which you are trying to solve?